# Cordova android app not showing icon on home screen

Tags: android, cordova, icons

We've got a web app powered by cordova to generate mobile apps. Everything does work on iOS.

We're trying to add the android platform and about everything works well except application icons.

The `config.xml` mostly follows what's [on the docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/images.html#android):

```
<widget
    id="xxx"
    version="xxx"
    ios-CFBundleVersion="xxx"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <description></description>
    <author email="xxx" href="xxx">xxx</author>
    <content src="index.html" />

    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />

    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
        <preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0" />
        <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
        <preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="normal" />

        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-Small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-Small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-Small@3x.png" width="87" height="87" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-83.5.png" width="83.5" height="83.5" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/Icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/iTunesArtwork@2x.png" width="1024" height="1024" />

        <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>

        <splash src="resources/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" height="2732"/>
    </platform>

    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />

        <icon src="resources/icons/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/icons/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />

        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/splash/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>

        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    </platform>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="mailto:*" />

    <universal-links>
        <ios-team-id value="xxx" />
        <host name="$host" scheme="$scheme" event="universal-link-clicked"/>
    </universal-links>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-fetch" spec="https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-fetch.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-disable-bitcode" spec="~1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="com.batch.cordova" spec="https://github.com/floo51/cordova-plugin.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-non-exempt-encryption" spec="~1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-universal-links-plugin" spec="~1.2.1" />
</widget>
```

There are different types of icons:

- APK file icon (works)
- Install screen (works)
- Apps menu (does not work)
- Home screen (does not work)
  [image]
- Runnings apps (does not work)
  [image]

Most weird is that it does work on simulator (nexus 5) but not on a OnePlus One or a Moto G4.

We're using cordova 6.5. All icons are resized according to [what's on the docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/images.html#android). Did we miss anything ?

Comment: Well the icon does work but its the default one which indicates something is wrong either with your `resources` folder or with your `platforms` folder. You should check if the `resources` folder contains every size of your icon and to fix problems like that you usually readd the android platform after deleting the `platforms` folder by running `cordova platform add android@latest`. You should also consider upgrading from cordova 6.5 to the most recent one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend two things:

1) Use `qualifier` instead of `density`. Example:

```
<icon src="resources/icons/ldpi.png" qualifier="ldpi" />
```

2) Add default icon & splash as a fallback in the root folder of your project:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<splash src="splash.png" />
```

Comment: Wow ! `qualifier` does actually fix the issue... Will need some documentation update. Thanks !